# Remove # from URL in ANGULARJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, server, glassfish-4.1

I'm  new in AngularJS framework.
I'm working in Netbeans 8.2, using Glassfish Server.
AngularJS version is 1.5.0

*I'm trying to remove the # symbol from the URL*, with no success until now.

So far I've tried:

1. to remove the "#/" from the href links in the index page
2. Add the  code in the head section
3. Add the  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true) in the script.js file

Until now if I do all the 3 steps written above, everytime i try to execute my application for every html page it gives me **ERROR 404 - NOT FOUND**.

For the code I'm following a tutorial on youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XsRugDQaGOo&list=PL6n9fhu94yhWKHkcL7RJmmXyxkuFB3KSl&index=27 this is the link of the video where it removes the **#** symbol.

The main differences are that I'm working with Netbeans and not with VisualStudio.

**HTML CODE**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>TODO supply a title</title>
    <base href="/">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="framework/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="framework/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body ng-app="Demo">
    <table style="font-family: Arial">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" class="header">
                <h1>WebSite Header </h1>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="leftMenu">
                <a href="home">Home</a>
                <a href="courses">Courses</a>
                <a href="students">Students</a>
            </td>
            <td class="mainContent">
                <div ng-view></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" class="footer"><b>Website Footer</b></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

**THIS IS THE SCRIPT CODE**

```
var app = angular.module("Demo",["ngRoute"]).config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider)
{
$routeProvider.when
("/home",
    {
        templateUrl: "templates/home.html",
        controller: "homeController"
    }
).when
("/courses",
    {
        templateUrl: "templates/courses.html",
        controller: "coursesController",
        caseInsensitiveMatch: true
    }
).when
("/students",
    {
        templateUrl: "templates/students.html",
        controller: "studentsController"
    }
).when
("/students/:Id",
    {
        templateUrl: "templates/studentDetails.html",
        controller: "studentDetailsController"
    }
).otherwise
(
    {
        redirectTo: "/home"
    }
);
//$locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
app.controller("homeController",function($scope)
{
  $scope.message = "HOME PAGE!";
});
app.controller("coursesController",function($scope)
{
  $scope.courses = ["C#", "VB.NET", "SQL SERVER", "ASP.NET"];
});
app.controller("studentDetailsController",function($scope,$http,$log,$routeParams)
{

  $http.get("getStudent",{params: {Id: $routeParams.Id}}).then(function(response)
  {
    $scope.studente = response.data;
    $log.info($scope.studente);
  },
  function(response)
  {
    $log.info($routeParams.Id);
    $log.error(response.status);
  });
});
app.controller("studentsController", function($scope,$http,$log,$route)
{
  $scope.reloadData = function()
  {
    $route.reload();
  }
  $http.get("StudentsController").then(function(response)
  {
    $scope.students = response.data;
  },
  function(response)
  {
    $log.error(response.status);
  });
});
```

Comment: Server also needs to be configured to account for the virtual paths. With the hash in the routing no server config is needed

Comment: @charlietfl how do I do that in Netbeans?  I saw in the tutorials that he modifies the _web.config_ file. Which file do I have to change and what do I need to write?

Comment: Netbeans is an IDE. Which IDE you use really isn't relevant, its the server side code/config that is

Comment: @charlietfl I know, I've already tried the same code on the server side (in the _web.xml_ file) but It's not working

Comment: Since your issue is server side suggest you create  question with the relevant code used there and tag it appropriately to the tech stack used server side. If you are able to navigate routes by clicking links in client side routing then issue is not angular specific